# Are programming language questions acceptable here

Tags: discussion

My questions are about some concepts of programming language. I was wondering if such questions are unacceptable here?

For example,

- One is "[Understand foreign function
  interface (FFI) and language
  binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440968/understand-foreign-function-interface-ffi-and-language-binding)"
- Another is "[Is there some nice
  description about language
  features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439060/is-there-some-nice-description-about-language-features)"?

One has been flagged as off-topic on Stack-overflow. This and the rate of reply both make me come here to ask if there may be a chance for match.

If they are completely unacceptable here as well, do you happen to know some places where I can ask these questions, and/or some suggestion on improving my questions?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 4):

I would think that both questions would be fine on this site.  I would not re-post them, however.  I would flag them on SO and ask the moderators to migrate them if they think it is appropriate.